# Why would a very electrically short helical antenna change significantly by adding 1 inch to both leads?

Tags: antenna

This question is in regards to high power transmission at 13.56 MHz.

I kind of understand the concepts of what an electrically short antenna is as well as how radiation resistance affects radiative efficiency (increased radiation resistance means increased efficiency.)

I've run into a situation where, adding one inch to the straight leads of a helical antenna has seemingly greatly reduced performance despite maintaining the same coil turn number, turn pitch, and circumference. The circumference of the antenna is such that it is ≪0.01λ, and the pitch is even smaller. The antenna is surrounded by a ground plane which also much smaller in diameter than the wavelength. If the radiation resistance equation for a small loop area with circumference ≪ λ/3 from Wikipedia page for [radiation resistance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radiation_resistance) is to be believed, the radiation resistance is R≪1. The equation for this is $$R_{rad}=320\pi^4\left(\frac{N\,A}{\lambda^2}\right)^2.$$

Why would simply adding λ/871 to the leads make such a difference?

I should add that I'm trying to couple power to something inside the coil.

Comment: Took me a while to realize "1 in" means "an inch"; that's a very useless measure, not because you used freedom units instead of proper SI units that people outside a single country can also work with, but because 1 inch might be much or very little relative to wavelength, and the rest of your antenna. Can you tell replace the "1 in" by something like "1/100 radius" or similar?

Comment: @MarcusMüller `freedom units` is a funny term ... it's more `shoot yourself in the foot units`

Comment: @jsotola you mean `lose a mars sonde units`?

Comment: Please show a picture of the antenna/coil with dimensions.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I have changed "1 inch" to the appropriate fraction of a wavelength at 13.56 MHz.

Comment: Which is the reflection coefficient before you add the 1 inch?

Comment: @Ender thanks! I'll have to re-read your question (it's been a while, sorry!), but it's really surprising to me now. 1/870 should practically never make a difference.

Comment: Please show the circuit the antenna connects to, and preferably a dimensioned diagram of the antenna, its surroundings, the coupled load, etc. From the minimal information provided, my guess is the antenna Q is extremely high (precisely because radiation resistance is low, but also *lower still*, depending on just how "surrounded" with ground plane it is), and so you've basically added some ~40nH to the inductance (it's not an antenna, it's an inductor with internal resistance dominant over radiation resistance?) and that's screwed up the tuning. So adjust L/C to compensate.

Answer (score 0):

Using an inductance calculator here, https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/tools/wire-self-inductance-calculator/

I estimate it should not be a problem with 40 nH at 13.6MHz  from 5 cm of wire. However distorting the coil geometry by > 0.1% may impact this. You can see this with light stress on the antenna using a network analyzer looking at s11. If you do not have one then use a splitter in reverse and rectify the reflection for a DVM reading using a hot-carrier or a Schottky diode.

I am surprised it is that small. It would be helpful to show your good test results without the added wire as small Helix antennae are not recommended for this low frequency.

**For RFID’s and any magnetic sensing or power transfer, it is best for the coil diameter to exceed the distance to target, otherwise it attenuates like a point source with quadratic losses.**

Rigidity is crucial in high gain helix antenna.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helical_antenna